# Matplotlib missing font metrics file

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I was trying to use latex in matplotlib and got the following error:

```
File ~/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/matplotlib/dviread.py:474, in Dvi._fnt_def_real(self, k, c, s, d, a, l)
    472 tfm = _tfmfile(fontname)
    473 if tfm is None:
--> 474     raise FileNotFoundError("missing font metrics file: %s" % fontname)
    475 if c != 0 and tfm.checksum != 0 and c != tfm.checksum:
    476     raise ValueError('tfm checksum mismatch: %s' % n)

FileNotFoundError: missing font metrics file: cmss17

<Figure size 432x288 with 1 Axes>
```

All I did was

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

mpl.rcParams["text.usetex"] = True
mpl.rcParams["text.latex.preamble"] = r"\usepackage{amsmath}"
plt.rcParams["font.size"] = 18

plt.plot([0, 1], [2, 3])
```

Any ideas on how to setup the font metrics file? I did try to install the cmss17 font, however, it did not help, I am still getting this error. I am using an M1 Mac.

Thanks in advance!